# How to make App Bundle for Google play on Unity3D 2018.1.4f

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a .aab file for my Unity3D game, but I can't find any option for .abb in build settings.

I'm using Unity 2018.1.4f.

Does this version of Unity not have support for .abb?

Answer (score 1):

2018.1 doesn't support app bundle, you need upgrade to 2018.3 at least.